# ImageView setBackround inside the activity dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

Inside my drawabale folder I have these images: levelone, leveltwo, level three.

i need to set the ImageView according to the inputted string as follows:

```
    levelindicatorImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.levelindicatorImageView);

    String tempo="R.drawable.level"+LevelReached;
    Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(tempo);
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        levelindicatorImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(replacer);
    } else {
        levelindicatorImageView.setBackground(replacer);
    }
    levelindicatorImageView.invalidate();
```

now inside LevelReached variable i have the needed level (one, two, three)
I need to set the Image R.drawable.leveltwo etc...

How is that possible please?
as getDrawable doesn't work with tempo (needs int)

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

### **Option 1:**

Simply use a switch-case to get the correct drawable, then set it as a background image as you normally would

```
// Get the level drawable resource id
int imageRes = R.drawable.default_image;
switch (levelReached) {
    case LEVEL_ONE: // 1
        imageRes = R.drawable.level_one;
        break;
    case LEVEL_TWO: // 2
        imageRes = R.drawable.level_two;
        break;
    ...
}

// Set the drawable as a background
levelIndicatorImageView.setBackgroundResource(imageRes);
```

Where LEVEL_ONE == 1; LEVEL_TWO == 2; as const or enum.

### **Option 2:**

You can find a drawable resource by name (as you wanted), but it is less recommended since it is more error prune. But if you must, use following example:

```
// Get the level drawable resource id
int imageRes = getResources().getIdentifier("level"+levelReached, "drawable", getPackageName());

// Set the drawable as a background
levelIndicatorImageView.setBackgroundResource(imageRes);
```

### Note:

You don't need to explicitly invalidate the view if you set the background since setting a new background will trigger invalidation by itself. So, this line:

```
levelindicatorImageView.invalidate();
```

is not needed.

Comment: hello, thanks for the help and sorry for the late response, it was a weekend and i had to get away. setBackground can not take int so levelIndicatorImageView.setBackground(imageRes) is not working any idea?

Comment: Hi James. LEVEL_ONE is a const defined as an enum - you need to define it. But you can simply compare to int - (1, 2,3 ..).

Comment: Regarding the first question - please use setBackgroundResource - updated the code in the answer.

Comment: did it with the switch and const. hope this is a good way of implementing it :D thanks a lot! and true levelindicatorImageView.invalidate(); is not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant append input string to image name, but what you can do is,
select the image based on input string and then If you have 3 different images,  try with ;

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("input one"))
{
   int id = R.drawable.<img one>;
}
else
{
   //so on
}

levelindicatorImageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable( id) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the levels to a resource, in this case, an `int`. An idiomatic way of doing this would be to store the levels as an enum, say

```java
enum Level { ONE, TWO, THREE }
```

Using an enum in this way allows you some flexibility with your level conventions. For example, if you later wanted to add the level `TWO_THIRDS`, there is nothing stoping you. Then, associate each level with a resource in an `EnumMap`, for example:

```java
Map<Level, Integer> levelResources = new EnumMap<Level, Integer>(Level.class);

levelResources.put(ONE, R.drawable.levelOne);
levelResources.put(TWO, R.drawable.levelTwo);
levelResources.put(THREE, R.drawable.levelThree);
```

Now, instead of passing around a string which describes your current level, you can pass around an enum, which you can use to determine the correct resource without concatenating strings. So, suppose that `levelReached` is of type `Level`, you could write:

```java
Integer tempo = levelResources.get(levelReached);
Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(tempo);
```

Comment: hello, ONE TWO THREE are giving me expression expected. any idea? thanks!

Comment: Yes, try removing the semi-colon at the end of the `enum Level { ... };` statement. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
public int getResourecId(String level) {
    if(level.equalsIgnoreCase("one"))
        return R.drawable.levelone;
    if(level.equalsIgnoreCase("two"))
        return R.drawable.leveltwo;
    if(level.equalsIgnoreCase("three"))
        return R.drawable.levelthree;
    return 0;
}
```

and then:

```
Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(getResourceId(LevelReached));
```